# Socket.IO Force synchronicity

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, socket.io

Here's what I want to do:

1. Connect to the socket
2. On setPermissions, begin a for Each from a string split
3. Inside the loop, send an emit for a json, and dont wait for a response to come ( because there wont be any ).

```
socket.on("setPermissions", function() {
        // Example: 1;2;3;4;5
        if(episodesString.split(';').length > 1)
        {
            var episodes = episodesString.split(';');
            episodes.forEach(function(episode){
                console.log(episode); //Console: 1
                socket.timeout(5000).emit("queue", {'type':'cm','id': episode,'pos':'end','temp':false,'duration':0});
            });
        }   
    });
```

This should, in theory, do the following:
Console: `1`
Emit the queue command with the argument json
Timeout after 5 seconds of waiting
Continue with next

Console: `2`
Emit the queue command with the argument json
Timeout after 5 seconds of waiting
Continue with next

Console: `3`
Emit the queue command with the argument json
Timeout after 5 seconds of waiting
Continue with next
*etc.*

Instead, what happens is
Console: `1`
Console: `2`
Console: `3`
Do all emits at once
Timeout all emits at once
Only 1 or 2 emits actually get through

How can I force socket.io to just do the forEach loop in sequential order?

Answer (score 1):

You can not achieve that using `socket.timeout`. You need to use `async` function that waits for X seconds (5 sec in your case) then calls `socket.emit`.

```
// put this in function somewhere in your code.
const sleep = (time) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time))
```

```
socket.on('setPermissions', function () {
  const episodes = episodesString.split(';')
  if (episodes.length < 2) return

  episodes.forEach(async (episode) => { // <-- Notice `async` here
    console.log(episode) 
    await sleep(5 * 1000) // awaits for 5 sec
    socket.emit('queue', { type: 'cm', id: episode, pos: 'end', temp: false, duration: 0 })
  })
})
```

this is same as above but using `for..of` loop.

```
socket.on('setPermissions2', async function () { // <-- Notice `async` here
  const episodes = episodesString.split(';')
  if (episodes.length < 2) return

  for (const episode of episodes) {
    console.log(episode) 
    await sleep(5 * 1000) // waits for 5 sec
    socket.emit('queue', { type: 'cm', id: episode, pos: 'end', temp: false, duration: 0 })
  }
})
```

Comment: `> 1` is not the same as `< 2`. both are wrong it should be just `if (episodes.length)`, or left out entirely because the loop wont loop if there is no items to loop over

Comment: @LawrenceCherone notice OP snippet, hes wants emit if array has length is greater than 1 (> 1),  not  zero. I am not sure why,  but OP is doing it. if OP wanted to emit only if array is not empty (length of array > 0) then yes, you are right `if (episodes.length)` should be used but since we are looping over, we don't need check `episodes.length` at all (loops wont run if length is zero).

Comment: To solve the mystery why I did >1:
Sleep deprivation, thanks for catching the bug. and for the help no less!

Sadly, I get the same result. Only the first three elements of the episode array are actually added, the rest is ignored.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Furthermore, the emit is still eternally waiting for a response, which it is not going to get.  So what its currently doing is: Writing every console.log at once, only adding 3 of the 15 items, and then waiting for something.

Comment: @CodingWolf "Only the first three elements of the episode array are actually added, the rest is ignored." wait what, that's not suppose to happen show me your client side code and `socket.emit` doesn't waits for response, it will only if you use `socket.timeout().emit` .

Comment: "That's not supposed to happen" is the story of my career. What you see up there is the client side code. The server is a project called Cytube, so I didn't write that part. Whenever I use emit without the timeout, it just gets stuck on it indefinitely.

Comment: @CodingWolf you mean [this](https://github.com/calzoneman/sync) project ? I think its because you are passing wrong data type, its expecting `object` & also its kicks you out if user doesnt have permission. see these [lines](https://github.com/calzoneman/sync/blob/3.0/src/channel/permissions.js#L142-L149)

Comment: @bogdanoff Thank you for your help, the code is working now.